# Hudson: Copy artifact from master to slave fails

Tags: hudson, jenkins

Is it possible to use the 'copy artifact' plugin to copy an artifact from a job that ran on master to a downstream job that runs on a slave node?

I'm getting an error on the slave that says:
hudson.util.IOException2: hudson.util.IOException2: Failed to extract /srv/hudson/jobs/myproject/builds/2011-04-29_10-28-54/archive/myartifact.foo

Obviously that path is not valid, as it points to the artifact folder  on master.

Am I missing something or is this just not possible?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. You can use the [Copy Artifact Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Copy+Artifact+Plugin) to copy any artifact to the slave.

For a first test I recommend to

- set up a job just with one 'Copy artifacts from another project' step
- set the 'Project name' to a job with your artifact
- set 'Which build' to 'Last successful build' (ensure there is one)
- keep the 'Artifacts to copy' and 'Target directory' empty to copy all artifacts to the slave workspace directory

Comment: sorry for the late accept, as i had a work-around for the problem i never looked back to the question. it perfectly works as you describe. is not specifying which artifacts to copy, the reason that it works now?