# Publishing to Artifactory using Jenkins

Tags: ant, jenkins, wildcard, artifactory

I am trying to use the Generic Jenkins-Artifactory plugin to deploy the contents of the Jenkins build workspace into Artifactory. This seems to be somewhat fine using the following wildcards

```
Web\*.msi=>Testing\Web
Web\DeploymentSettings\*.xml=>Testing\Web\DeploymentSettings
Database\Scripts\**=>Testing\Database
```

However, when it comes to moving the contents of 'Database\Scripts' from the Jenkins workspace, empty folders under 'Database\Scripts' do not get copied into Artifactory. Non-empty folders however are copied successfully. It is important that I maintain the directory integrity/structure so it's a must that I copy these across.

I have considered placing empty text files in the empty directories to have them copy over successfully but I don't want to "pollute" the package.

Please help :-)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there is no workaround -other than dummy files in the directories.
I see some bugs in Jenkins releated to handling empty directories.
[JENKINS-7260 Clone workspace doesn't copy empty directories when cloning entire workspace](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-7260)
[JENKINS-20654Empty folders are not copied to the slave](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-20654)

Could you check if answer posted in [Hudson: Copy artifact from master to slave fails](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5840121/1849837) helps?

Comment: Thanks for your help. We decided to zip the master folder and place it in to Artifactory so that we maintain the directory structure